# Displaying a list of checkboxes in my form

Tags: forms, playframework

I want to display many checkboxes inline like:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckboxA" value="optionA"> A
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckboxB" value="optionB"> B
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline">
  <input type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckboxC" value="optionC"> C
</label>
```

So I have my form like:

```
val form: Form[SearchForm] = Form(
  mapping(
    "letters" -> list(text)
  )
```

)(SearchForm.apply)(SearchForm.unapply _)

Can I somehow pre-populate my form with the data or do I have to pass another variable with my view that has this 'letters' data?

```
val letters = List[String]("A", "B", "C", ...)
```

If I can't pass this letters val down with my view, then I guess I just pass another variable with my model and just iterate over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the helper [`inputCheckboxGroup`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputCheckboxGroup.scala.html) ?

That will pre-populate the form elements from your model but you'll still have to provide the checkbox group with the set of possible values.

For example:

```
@views.html.helper.inputCheckboxGroup(
  form("letters"),
  options = Seq("A" -> "alpha", "B" -> "beta", "C" -> "gamma"),
  '_label -> "My cool checkbox"
)
```

and the form filled with:

```
val form: Form[SimpleForm] = Form(mapping(
    "letters" -> list(text)
  )(SimpleForm.apply)(SimpleForm.unapply))

SimpleForm.form.fill(SimpleForm(List("A", "B")))
```

Would render a checkbox group like this:

```
[x] alpha [x] beta [ ] gamma
```

Comment: Could you include the definition of SimpleForm?

Comment: ‘case class SimpleForm(letters: List[String])’

Comment: Good reference here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#defining-a-form